# Euler's theorem with a product of primes

Tags: number-theory

Could someone tell me why it is, that if you have a product of primes, say 15, then if you use the slightly modified Euler's theorem, then the equation works for every number, not only for relative primes to n=3*5?

$$x^{\phi(3*5)+1} \equiv x \mod (3*5)$$

How could I show this?
(Question is related to RSA if you know it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m$ be a product of **distinct** primes, and let $p$ be any prime divisor of $m$.

If $p$ does not divide $x$, then we have $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, and therefore $x^{\varphi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, and therefore  $x^{\varphi(m)+1}\equiv x\pmod{p}$.

If $p$ divides $x$, then again $x^{\varphi(m)+1}\equiv x\pmod{p}$, since both sides are congruent to $0$.

Thus $x^{\varphi(m)+1}\equiv x\pmod{p}$ for every prime divisor of $m$. Since $m$ is the product of distinct primes, it follows that $x^{\varphi(m)+1}\equiv x\pmod{m}$.

**Remark:** The condition that $m$ is a product of distinct primes is necessary. For example, $3^{\varphi(9)+1}\not\equiv 3\pmod{9}$.

Comment: "Since m is the product of distinct primes..." this sentence is not 100% clear yet, could you please explain it? Thank you!

Comment: Leave it, got it right now! :) Cheers!

Comment: This is part of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. To simplify things, suppose $m=pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes (relatively prime is enough). The assertion is that if $p$ divides $a-b$ and $q$ divides $a-b$ then $pq$ divides $a-b$. So we want to show that if $p$ and $q$ both divide $c$, then $pq$ divides $c$, The usual proof uses the Bezout identity. There are integers $x$, $y$ such that $px+qy=1$. So $pxc+qyc=c$. But it is clear that $pq$ divides the left side.

Answer (score 1):

By Fermat's little theorem, $3|x(x^2-1);5|x(x^4-1)$ for all integer $x$

$\displaystyle\implies x(x^{\text{lcm}(2,4)}-1)$ will be divisible by lcm$(3,5)$

Now $\displaystyle4|\phi(15)\implies x(x^{\phi(15)}-1)$ is divisible by $ x(x^4-1)$ which is already divisible by lcm$(3,5)$